# Add help text/metadata information in Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is like this

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_get_StudentInfo]

            @vaule nvarchar(50),
            @field nvarchar(50)
as
    select * from StudentMaster where @field=@value
```

Its gets two value first is @value and otehr is FIELD. now i am fetching student information with two different keys one is SID and other is OSID. both are unique.What i am doing here is if i have SID as field and its corresponding value it will fetch that info and if i add OSID as field and its corresponding value it will get those data.

Now query is working fine but how do i get to show the metadata dictionary value when i write Sp in my C# code. Its the help text which show up if you write any system stored procedure. [image]

as of now its says no metadata documentation available.How to add those details.

I am coding on C# MVC.

Comment: do you have the actual .cs code behind code that you can show..?

Comment: It looks like we have another case of _optimistic programming_. This time it is expecting that the value of a variable will suddenly be interpreted as the name of a column and the column's value will be substituted. A nearby variable will, oddly, just supply a value. If that is your intent then you'll need to look into dynamic SQL using [`sp_Execute_SQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).